# Install Let's Encrypt for multiple domains on same server

Tags: ssl, https, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have a Digital Ocean Droplet and changed A-Records for 5 domains to point to the server.
I would like to install SSL (lets encrypt) for all 5 domains.
Is this possible?

I run this setup to backend identify the domain name and using this change the language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is.
It depends on what challenge you're going to use.
If you're using the certbot (which I can recommend!) you can simply append multiple domains with `-d`

For example (you can even use wildcards):

```
certbot -d domain1.tld,domain2.tld,domain3.tld,*.domain3.tld
```

There is some good documentation on [DigitalOcean itself](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Otherwise check out [the website](https://certbot.eff.org/) or the [official docs](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Just perfect. Only thought i would allow for subdomains.

Comment: Note: alternatively, you can use just one `-d` with multiple domains comma-separated

Comment: I just wanted to note that if you are running apache you need to state it. If you later want to add another domain to your server run: $
sudo certbot --apache -d yourdomain.com  
or use the comma-separated method for multiple additions